# Segmentation Fault: 11 when trying to sort linked list by odds and evens

Tags: c++, linked-list, segmentation-fault, nodes, chain

I'm trying to complete an assignment for my Data Structures course but I keep getting a segfault in one of my functions.

What I have this function doing is creating two new chains, one for even numbers and another for odds, incrementing through the original list, and populating the new chains based on whether or not the element is even or odd.

What I am stuck on is getting the last node from the odd chain to link to the beginning of the even chain, because the chains need to be linked together at the end of the function.

```
void chain :: oddAndEvenOrdering()
{
//This function reorders the list 
//such a way that all odd numbers precede all even numbers. 
//Note that for two odd (even) 
//numbers i and j, the ordering between 
//i and j should be intact after reordering.
// Create empty chain to store odds
chain *oddChain = new chain(100);
chainNode *oddNode = oddChain->firstNode;
// Create empty chain to store evens
chain *evenChain = new chain(100);

int countOdd = 0;
int countEven = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < listSize-1; i++)
{
    if (*this->get(i) % 2 == 0)
    {
        evenChain->insert(countEven, *this->get(i));
        countEven++;
    } else {
        oddChain->insert(countOdd, *this->get(i));
        oddNode = oddNode->next;
        countOdd++;
    }

}
chainNode *evenNode = evenChain->firstNode; 
oddNode->next = evenNode;

delete this;
this->firstNode = oddChain->firstNode;

}
```

Comment: Without even reading the problem, I see a big faux pa here:  `delete this;
this->firstNode = oddChain->firstNode;`

Comment: @ZacHowland Now here is what I am doing   
     `for (int i = 0; i < listSize; i++)

 {
  this->erase(i);
 }`
however when I do "this->output();" a little less than half the list still exists.

Also `oddNode = oddNode->next;` and `oddNode->next = evenNode` are causing the seg faults, when I comment them out there is no seg fault.

Comment: This is because whenever you call `erase`, your list shrinks by one, but you still increment `i`. So you are only erasing every second element of your list. A better alternative:

`while (!this->empty())
{
    erase (0);
}`

Comment: Thanks for the advice, what I came up with was `while(this->get(0) != NULL) {
  this->erase(0);
 }` which gets the job done. Now I am stuck connecting the lists...

Comment: Without knowing how your chain classes are implemented, I would propose that you iterate over each element of `oddChain` and copy its elements into `this`, and then iterate over `evenChain` and copy every i-th element of it into position `i+oddChain->listSize` of `this`. Then delete both `oddChain` and `evenChain`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will most certainly produce an error:

```
delete this;
this->firstNode = oddChain->firstNode;
```

You delete `this` and then try to access its members.

Comment: Yeah I knew that would be bad. I'm trying to erase all the contents of the list and then point the first node to the first node of the oddchain. The class has an erase method so I'll just iterate through the original chain and erase it that way.

Comment: There is something else that I noticed: It does not seem like you copy the elements of `oddChain` into `this`, but you replace the pointer to the first node. However, you have to delete `oddChain` at some point. Are you sure you won't delete the data of your sorted chain in the process?

Answer (score 1):

Your memory issue has already been addressed in Anton's answer, but you could avoid it completely if you implemented your container in such a way that is consistent with the standard library.  For example:

```
std::vector<int> vec { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 };
std::partition(vec.begin(), vec.end(), [](int i)
{
    return i % 2;
});
```

This will put all of the odds at the start of the vector and all of the evens at the end.

Comment: Can you please give me a bit more detail about how that function works? It looks very interesting.